# How to update Chart.js with new data from socket.io?

Tags: javascript, node.js, charts, socket.io

On console, I perfectly get my arrays shown, I just can't update the data on chart. The chart remains blank (invisible).

Chart:

```
var myChart = new Chart(ctx, {
  type:'doughnut',
  data:{
    labels:[],
    datasets:[{
      label:'Bet',
      data:[],
      backgroundColor:[
        '#1CE6FF',
        '#FF34FF',
        '#BB4345',
        '#008941',
        '#006FA6',
        'rgb(163, 0, 89)'
      ],
      borderWidth:3,
      borderColor:'#000'
    }]
  },
  options:{
    legend:{
      display:false
    }
  }
});
```

Getting Data:

```
io.on('playerBets', function(data){
  myChart.data.datasets.data = data;
  myChart.update();
  console.log(data);
});
```

Getting Labels:

```
io.on('playerNames', function(data){
  myChart.data.labels = data;
  myChart.update();
  console.log(data);
});
```

Comment: Does your chart work correctly without using **socket.io**?

Comment: Yes, It was working, then I transferred data to the server and receive it with socket.io. console logs it fine.

Comment: Could you post a sample of the `console.log()`?

Comment: `(6) [100, 200, 25, 5, 19, 21]` there is some more code, this is just thumbnail on the log.

Comment: And what's the `console.log()` output for labels? Are you maybe having a desync between the labels and data?

Comment: It's the same array, client gets data from the server fine, the chart does not get it for some reason.